# uefi shell - download a file via https

Tags: uefi, https, tls, python3

I am experimenting with uefi shell from and I wish to implement the following scenario :

- boot into uefi shell
- download a a startup.nsh script from https remote resource
- run the downloaded startup.nsh script

Any ideas on how to accomplish https download via uefi shell?

I tried building python368 port from edk2 but it seems to have an issue with import socket.

Also, any guide on how to build such capability for efi would be great.

Thank you

Comment: We aren't a script writing service, we need a single, specific question, and we need you to tell us what you've done. Just to make things clear, currently your question is "hey, I had an idea, have any of you programmed this solution already?"

Comment: So Ive build python368 from edk2, it lack support for socket so I cant import urllib or socket.. I see that lua can also work, not sure how to build lua for uefi shell env. Im looking for the most suitable technology rather than a script. Thank you

Comment: Sorry, it's not that this isn't a good question, it's that this isn't a good question for here. I recommend you find a programmers forum, where discussion and open-ended discussion is done. You're likely to find good information there on a broad set of questions like this. But here we ask for single, specific questions that can have a correct answer, and that's not what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the instructions provided in Py368ReadMe.txt file available at https://github.com/tianocore/edk2-libc/blob/master/AppPkg/Applications/Python/Python-3.6.8/Py368ReadMe.txt

Copied those instructions for quick reference here.

6. Enabling socket support
   ===================================
7. enable {"_socket", init_socket}, in PyMod-3.6.8\Modules\config.c
8. enable LibraryClasses BsdSocketLib and EfiSocketLib in Python368.inf
9. Build Python interpreter application using below command
   build -a X64 -p AppPkg\AppPkg.dsc
10. copy Build\AppPkg\RELEASE_VS2017\X64\Python.efi to \Efi\Tools on your
    target system. Replace "RELEASE_VS2017", in the source path, with
    values appropriate for your tool chain.

We were able to run HTTP Client and download a file from HTTP server with Python interpreter enabled with the socket module.